# Crash in a fast function to replace a specific color in a bmp

Tags: c, colors, bitmap, pixel, bmp

Suddenly I got in rampage of creating a really fast function that replaces a specific color in a memory-buffered bmp image. I am testing with 40x40 image, thus it is padless one.

[image]

And here is what I have so far:

```
union
{
    unsigned long ulColor;
    unsigned char byteColor[4];
} oldColor;
union
{
    unsigned long ulColor;
    unsigned char byteColor[4];
} newColor;

typedef unsigned long DWORD;
typedef unsigned short WORD;
typedef unsigned char BYTE;

DWORD
bitfox_color_replace_data
(BYTE *buff, BYTE old_r, BYTE old_g, BYTE old_b, BYTE new_r, BYTE new_g, BYTE new_b)
{
    #define OFFSET_OF_PIXELS    0xA
    #define OFFSET_OF_WIDTH     0x13
    #define OFFSET_OF_HEIGHT    0x17

    DWORD* buffPixels   = (DWORD*)&buff[OFFSET_OF_PIXELS];
    DWORD* buffWidth    = (DWORD*)&buff[OFFSET_OF_WIDTH];
    DWORD* buffHeight   = (DWORD*)&buff[OFFSET_OF_HEIGHT];
    WORD pad            = (*buffWidth) % 4;

    DWORD pixLines, pixColumns;
    DWORD pixels_replaced = 0;

    oldColor.byteColor[0] = old_r;
    oldColor.byteColor[1] = old_g;
    oldColor.byteColor[2] = old_b;

    for(pixLines = 0; pixLines < *buffHeight; pixLines++)
    {
        for(pixColumns = 0; pixColumns < (*buffWidth * 3) - 3; pixColumns += 3) //-2 -3
        {
            newColor.byteColor[0] = buff[*buffPixels + (pixLines * (*buffWidth)) + pixColumns];
            newColor.byteColor[1] = buff[*buffPixels + (pixLines * (*buffWidth)) + pixColumns + 1];
            newColor.byteColor[2] = buff[*buffPixels + (pixLines * (*buffWidth)) + pixColumns + 2];

            if(oldColor.ulColor == newColor.ulColor)
            {
                memcpy(&buff[*buffPixels + (pixLines * (*buffWidth)) + pixColumns], newColor.ulColor, 3);
                pixColumns += 3;
                pixels_replaced++;
            }
        }
    }
    return pixels_replaced;
}
```

The problem is that it crashes.. And I am trying to figure out what is responsible for that.

Comment: Improvement suggestion for a faster function: the expression buff[*buffPixels + (pixLines * (*buffWidth)) + pixColumns appears several times. Think about using a pointer to reference the pixel in the image to replace this expression.

Comment: Also the offsets of width/height are wrong. They are with 1 byte ahead.

Answer (score 0):

The instruction :

```
pixColumns += 3;
```

appears twice, in the "for" statement and after the color replacement.
The second one is too much.

Comment: Ahh It had to be `pixColumns -= 3;` . I hope that silly mistake is responsible.